# bluebird coroutine no executing at all

Tags: javascript, promise, command-line-interface, bluebird

I am trying to implement a CLI version of the Rock Paper Scissors game. I am using the inquirer module to handle IO.  My main function looks like this:

```
RockPaperScissors.prototype.gameLoop = function()
{
var x;
var Promise = require('bluebird');


//simple promise test
//this.playGame().then(function(){ console.log("The end");});

Promise.coroutine(function*()
{

    //for(x=0;x<this.maxTurns;x++)
    //{
        console.log('Printing '+ x.toString());
        var action = yield this.playGame();
    //}    

    if(this.playerScore > this.serverScore) { console.log('Player wins match');} else {console.log('Server wins match');  }    

});
};

exports.RockPaperScissors = RockPaperScissors;
```

The playGame() function returns a promise made by using new Promise(). If I do this:

```
this.playGame().then(function(){ console.log("The end");});
```

The promise executes correctly. However, when used inside Promise.coroutine(), nothing is executed. What am I missing here?

This is the code for the playGame() function:

```
RockPaperScissors.prototype.playGame = function()
{

    var inq = require('inquirer');  
    var rand = require('random-js');
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var promise = require('bluebird');

    //make possibilities local
    var possibilities = this.possibilities;

    console.log ('------------------ Stats ----------------');
    console.log ('Player: ' +this.playerScore+'  Server: '+this.serverScore);
    console.log ('-----------------------------------------');

    var question1 ={
        type:'rawlist',
        name:'option',
        message:'Please choose Rock, paper or scissors:',
        choices:['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
    };

    return new promise(function(resolve,reject)
    {
       inq.prompt([question1],function(answers)
       {
            console.log('You chose '+answers.option);
            var playerObject = answers.option;
            //random with Mersenne Twister API
            var r = new rand(rand.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());
            var myPlay =r.integer(0,2);
            var serverObject ='';
            switch(myPlay)
            {
                case 0:
                    serverObject='Rock';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    serverObject ='Paper';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    serverObject='Scissors';
                    break;
            }

            var result='', action='';
            //choose winner by using a lodash function!
            _.forEach(possibilities,function(e){
                if (e[0]==serverObject && e[1] ==playerObject) 
                {
                     result=e[2];
                     action=e[3];
                }
            });

            console.log('I chose ' + serverObject+ "\n")
            console.log (result);

            if (action=='win') {this.playerScore++;}
            if (action=='lose'){this.serverScore++;}
            resolve(action);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Try to [promisify at the lowest level only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) (which in your case would be only the `prompt` method). Put everything else in a `.then` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.coroutine()` *"returns a function that can use yield to yield promises"* ([doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html#promise.coroutine)), but you're not actually calling that function.

You probably want something like this:

```
Promise.coroutine(function*() {
...
})();
//^^ calling it
```

Comment: I had to make some extra modifications in order to get it to work. For example, I had to save a reference to the "this" object and pass it in as an argument to the generator function, as it seems the this context gets lost (bound to a different value) when inside promises. I also had to to this to the playGame() function.  I still don't know why promises do that.

Comment: @tutiplain `bluebird` has a [`bind`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html) method that you can use to set the `this` for a function. So something like this: `Promise.bind(this).coroutine(function*() { ... })`.

Comment: @robertklep: Rather `Promise.coroutine(function*() {…}).call(this)`. But have a look at my answer for the better solution which also takes care of the `this` issue.

Answer (score 3):

`Promise.coroutine` is a higher-order function, i.e. it takes a generator function and returns another function that, when called, will return the promise you're looking for. As @robertklep said, you're not even calling that returned function.

Instead, you are however supposed to wrap the complete method in `Promise.coroutine`, instead of calling it within the method. Your code should look like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

RockPaperScissors.prototype.gameLoop = Promise.coroutine(function*() {
    // simple promise test:
    // yield this.playGame();
    // console.log("The end");

    for (var x=0;x<this.maxTurns;x++) {
        console.log('Printing '+ x.toString());
        var action = yield this.playGame();
    }

    if (this.playerScore > this.serverScore) {
        console.log('Player wins match');
    } else {
        console.log('Server wins match');
    }
});
```

Comment: HI, this looks much cleaner than my approach. Why does this preserve the value of "this"? I'm just trying to understand why sometimes it has a different object than one would expect.

Comment: Because the function created by `Promise.coroutine` does call the generator function with its `this` value.